# Does anyone know how to fix the eyes while soft body effect is applyed?

Tags: mesh, bones, soft-body

Thank you for your time.

A problem has occurred  with the eyes of my character, after I apply a SoftBody effect sometimes the eyes go out of his head.

While the normal walk animation the eyes do what they should be doing.
After a few tinkering and playing around with the soft body settings they all make the eyes go wonkey at times.

The eyes are there own objects, and boned to the mesh.
I hope someone knows how to fix this, I am new to blender and mostly of the time I don't know what I am doing ^^;

[image: Wonkey eyes] [image: wonkey eyes and bones] [image: Setting1] [image: settings2]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For everyone stuck with this problem.

The main issue is the Mass, Blender extends the vertex group so the jiggle effect affects the head which causes the head to also have this slight jiggle.
While the eyes are locked in place by the bones.
The Speed, should be on 1.000 it makes the belly jiggle slower but also the affected head.

By changing my soft body settings like in the picture below I have solved this issue, and turned off the soft body edges.

[image]

I hope this answer will help for those who have this issue.